# Include Toolbar Pager in custom product collection in custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, product-collection, toolbar, pager

I have a custom page where I am listing the custom product collection. I am using the default catalog/product/list.phtml as template to display the page. It's listing fine like the category page. But it's missing the toolbar pager. I tried the code in the following way

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="customization/product_searchbycity" name="searchbycity" as="searchbycity" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
            </block>
</reference>
```

And in the block

```
class Probytes_Customization_Block_Product_Searchbycity extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
        $data['address'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('city-to-search');
        $model = Mage::getModel('customization/citysearch');
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection = $model->searchResult($data,$collection);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

It's not showing the toolbar pager in the custom page. I need the page like the category page. Please anyone help on this.

Comment: Check this link if you can helpful: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221785/how-to-get-all-visible-out-of-stock-products-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link. It's working fine.

http://navaneeth.me/add-toolbar-pager-custom-product-collection-magento/#.WD6xaHV9601