# How to get all visible out of stock products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-collection, out-of-stock

I checked into [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157193/how-to-get-only-out-of-stock-products-in-magento-2/213906#213906) and got my nearest answer but not as we usually expecting from magento.

I want all out of stock product which can visible in store front means have respective product landing page (PDP). 
which means exclude `Not Visible Individually` and enable products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing **R&D** found a solution to get all the out of stock products

```
<?php

namespace [VENDOR_NAME]\[MODULE_NAME]\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class OoSProducts extends Template
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollection;


    /**
     * @var Visibility
     */
    protected $_productVisibility;

    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    protected $_productStatus;


    /**
     * OoSProducts constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollection
     * @param Visibility $productVisibility
     * @param Status $productStatus
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollection,
        Visibility $productVisibility,
        Status $productStatus
    )  {

        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->_productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        $this->_productStatus = $productStatus;

    }

    /**
     * Out of Stock Product Collection
     * @return $this|\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function getOutofstockProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();

        $collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);

        $collection = $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku', 'product_url'))
            ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
            ->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            )
            ->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
            ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 0])
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
            ->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**pt 1.** To exclude product visibility `Not Visible Individually`, use this method.

```
$this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds()  returns the 

self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH 
self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
self::VISIBILITY_BOTH
```

**pt 2.** Get all enabled product, Use below method

```
$this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds() returns

self::STATUS_ENABLED
```

**pt 3.** `$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);`

It is important to set the **has_stock_status_filter** flag to **true** to get proper results for Out of stock products.

**Note:** [**VENDOR_NAME**]\[**MODULE_NAME**] should be replaced by your project directory names i.e vendor name and its module name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code In your collection

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();

    if (false === strpos($select->__toString(), 'cataloginventory_stock_status')) {
        $website = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite();
        $this->_objectManager->get(
            'Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status'
        )
            ->addStockStatusToSelect($select, $website);

    }

    $field = 'salable desc';

    $field = new \Zend_Db_Expr('IF(stock_status_index.qty > 0, 0, 1)');

    $select->order($field);
```